# How to use themify configs with ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb

Tags: reactjs, sass, mixins

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {

@include themify {

```
background-color: $ant-scroll-color !important;
```

}

border-radius: 10px;

}

Above code snippet is  not working

Requirement is to integrate dark and light theme for web component. I just want to change the scroll bar color in chrome according light and dark theme . Above **@include themify** method is used to configure colors. but this method isn't working with **::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Answer: 

 1. add this code in to mixins.scss . basically you are creating cutoms
    mixin for scroll bar colors

@mixin scrollbars() {
  // For Google Chrome
  @include themify {
    &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background: $ant-scroll-color;
    }
  }
  @include themify {
    &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
      background: $ant-scroll-color;
    }
  }
  @include themify {
    &::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      background: $white-color;
    }
  }
  // For Internet Explorer
  & {
    scrollbar-face-color: $ant-scroll-color;
    scrollbar-track-color: $ant-scroll-color;
  }
}

 2. add a ref to div which that use scroll in styles.scss
.customDiv{
overflow:auto:
@include scrollBars();
}
```